# Add class to ng-class inside ng-grid cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ng-class

I am quite new to Angular. I want to apply a custom class in ng-class in ng-grid's custom cell template. I am familiar with the overall usage of "ng-class". The default template is as follows:

```
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>    {{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></div>
```

Now, I want to add a new class which is based on the row's data. Say:

```
ng-class="myClass:row.entity.Flag == 'something'"
```

**Question:**
There is already a **col.colIndex()** in ng-class which is required by ng-grid. Now how to add my class with it?

I know it seems easy but it is not working.

I have tried following things:

1. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
3. Tried `ng-class="[col.colIndex(),{myClass:row.entity.Flag == something}]"`. Didn't work.
4. //scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

I just want a working 'ng-grid' template (which is defined above).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
row.entity.subGridOptions.Flag
```

Comment: Sorry @Jesse, didn't get you...

Can you fit that in the following line?

    $scope.gridOptions {
    cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>    {{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</span></div>'
}

I want to have additional class "myClass" to 'ng-class="col.colIndex()".'

Comment: Hi, I am still looking for answer on other pages,

Just wondering, will this work? I am adding extra <div> tag so I don't need to delete the built in ' ng-class="col.colIndex()" '.


`<div ng-class="myClass: something==true">
<default cellTemplate Here>
</div>`

Sorry for inappropriate formatting

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after further research.

I wanted to add a class through which I can strike-through the data on the ng-grid row. I was applying it to the `rowTemplate`, but rowTemplate in itself do not have any textual data.

I have to apply it inside `cellTemplate`, which is actually going to contain the text.

@Jesse, thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class="{\'red\': row.entity.Expiration == \'No\'}"

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.